# Is "the benefits of this will much more" correct?

Tags: future, copular-verbs

Is this sentence correct?

> The benefits of this will much more

or it should be like this:

> The benefits of this will **be** much more

Comment: I think you need to supply some more context, so we can see what you're trying to say.  Neither sentence makes much sense on its own, like this.

Comment: @David Wallace For example: "Eat fruit instead cookies!The benefits of this will much more". In this context.

Comment: OK. You want "The benefits of this will __be__ much more". Usually "will" indicates the future tense, and there needs to be another verb in the sentence, for this to be the future tense __of__.  Also, "Eat fruit instead __of__ cookies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Will** is an auxiliary verb (indicating the future tense) and a main verb should be used, so the second sentence (with **be**) is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Actually these two sentence fragments can both be used in grammatically correct sentences.
For example:

> **The benefits of this will much more** align with the project's goals than will those of Option 2.

or

> **The benefits of this will *be* much more** evident in the coming weeks.

Answer (score 2):

"Eat fruit instead cookies!The benefits of this will much more."

Even with adding "be", you don't have a complete thought. The benefits of this will be much more ... what? If you mean that it will have more benefits and you don't find it necessary to describe or identify those benefits, then write, for example, "This will have more benefits," or probably better, "This will have greater benefits."